# Expanding on the API roles

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Expanding on the API roles using Keycloak

when I try to make an API call to

```
http://localhost:8080/keycloak/url/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

with some data:

```
{
    client_id : 'clientId',
    username : 'name',
    password : '@#$%^&',
    grant_type : "password"

}
```

Its showing an error

> Client secret not provided in request.

Comment: You need to send your client secret with your data, your error message is very clear about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak is expecting secret key.
 The client that you are trying to access might have the access type ( on the first tab) as Confidential or Bearer-only.
In that case you need to send the secret key which you can take from the **Credentials** tab.

### Update:

```
http://server_url/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

{
  "username": "",
  "password": "",
  "realm": "",
  "redirect_url": "",
  "client_secret": "",
  "grant_type": ""
}
```

Mare sure choose the x-www-form-urlencoded, while sending the request.

Comment: can you please tell me the format in which we should send the secret key?